# How to implement tile rearranging like the Windows Phone home page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm using a grid of HubTile in my app, and I'd like to be able to rearrange (aka reorder the items by tapping and hold ) the tile like how the Windows Phone home page does it. 
I have come across something a bit similar - [A Gesture-Driven Windows Phone Todo List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428088/A-Gesture-Driven-Windows-Phone-To-Do-List), but I don't think it is readily usable. Is there some kind of open source library or commercial product that does that well. I really don't want to roll my own since the deadline is near and I need to leverage as much as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a WrapPanel. If you add your Hub Tiles to the WrapPanel, it would give you the same effect as the Windows Phone Home Page. 
The following links should help you understand how to go about the WrapPanel.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth

http://www.kotancode.com/2010/12/29/wp7-presenting-listbox-items-inside-a-wrappanel/

Once that is done, you could use touch manipulations to move the Hub Tiles around.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/07/08/enabling-touch-manipulations-on-windows-phone.aspx

First, group all the Hub Tiles into a List<> or an ObservableCollection<>. (I would advice using an ObservableCollection)

Use the touch manipulations to move the Hub Tile around. Based on the position of the Hub Tile (when the touch manipulation is done), you could rearrange the order of the Hub Tiles in the ObservableCollection. Update the ListBox.

By this I mean, that if the HubTile[3] is dragged and moved to the top of the Listbox, in the List<>, change the index of HubTile[3] to HubTile[0], and update the index of the rest of the HubTiles. When you refresh the ListBox, you should get the HubTiles rearranged.

You could create a StoryBoard for the animations.

Comment: First, thank you very much for the links. The first two links are very useful. But for the last link that the detail is missing. In the article "A Gesture-Driven Windows Phone Todo List App", it already shows me how to use the touch manipulation for tap-hold reorder of the items a bit like (not exactly) the start page of WP7/8. The part I'm missing is how to do reorder for grid layout instead of a vertical list layout. Any useful info on that? Thx in advance. Also I edited my question a bit to make it clearer of the intention of my question.

Comment: Check the edit in the answer. It should give you an approach to solving your problem.

Comment: I also struck in the same situation, and urgently need solution of this problem. Please give me some help to get over this(code if  possible).

Comment: @imgen Can you help me I am also struck in the same issue

Comment: @mayank.karki If you just want list reordering, you can goto https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/WP7-ClearStyle
I contributed a few fixes to it. But not related to reordering I think. 
If you want grid layout reordering, I cannot help you. I haven't solved that issue myself yet.